# Cannot Connect to Localhost in Windows

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

How can I access my local phpmyadmin with my web browser? I tried it on both Firefox and Chrome and both cannot load. I have XAMPP and I am working on Vista.

Comment: Try localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: I just typed in http://localhost/phpmyadmin and it still won't load. I am trying to create a login page for a website and so that's why I need to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your XAMPP working?

Try: `http://localhost/`

You should see the XAMPP console and from there you can go to phpmyadmin.

If you don't see the console is because XAMPP is not running.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I did have XAMPP running but Apache wasn't checked. After I checked the box, I can enter into the XAMPP console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the port that you using :

1. Open the file [XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf.
2. Then search for the string “ServerName”

For example in my httpd.conf the result is : ServerName localhost:8081

Then I use `http://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin`